# Storing results on web3 call in JavaScript Object

Tags: web3js, infura

#### Disclaimer: Terrible at Javascript

I am trying to loop through events and store the block number, to and from accounts in a Javascript object. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but it isnt working as planned. I would appreciate any pointers on this.

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3(`https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{SOME_PROJECT_ID}}`));

var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress);
var accounts = {};


// Crawl the Chain from the Contract Deployment Date till the latest block
contract.getPastEvents(
    'Transfer',
    {
      fromBlock: 8437000,
      toBlock: 'latest'
    },(error, events) => { 

    if (!error){
      var obj=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(events));
      var array = Object.keys(obj)

    //   Looping through returned array and adding to the account{} JavaScript Object
      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        accounts[obj[array[i].blockNumber]] = obj[array[i]].blockNumber; 
        accounts[obj[array[i]._from]] = obj[array[i]].returnValues._from; 
        accounts[obj[array[i]._to]] = obj[array[i]].returnValues._to; 
    }
    }
    else {
      console.log(error)
}

// This prints nothing
for (var i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
    console.log(accounts[i].blockNumber);
}
// The result of this is `[ [ 'undefined', '0x811573775614C5290690E9788c373111c1543D7A' ] ]` which is just one item.
console.log(Object.entries(accounts));
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    accounts[obj[array[i].blockNumber]] = obj[array[i]].blockNumber; 
    accounts[obj[array[i]._from]] = obj[array[i]].returnValues._from; 
    accounts[obj[array[i]._to]] = obj[array[i]].returnValues._to; 
}
```

To this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    accounts[obj[array[i]] = {
        blockNumber: obj[array[i]].blockNumber,
        _from: obj[array[i]].returnValues._from,
        _to: obj[array[i]].returnValues._to
    };
}
```

Or better yet, to this:

```
for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    accounts[key] = {
        blockNumber: val.blockNumber,
        _from: val.returnValues._from,
        _to: val.returnValues._to
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have gone with the second option, . I need to add a closing bracket `]` to it , but now when i run the code, i get an empty bracket i.e. `[]`

Comment: the third option works